# while running gulp watch i got, the terminal of my vs code stopped at starting 'watch'

Tags: css, saas

```
var gulp = require("gulp");

var autoprefixer = require("gulp-autoprefixer");

gulp.task("style", function () {

    return gulp.src("./style.css").pipe(autoprefixer()).pipe(gulp.dest("build"));
});

gulp.task("watch", function () {

    gulp.watch("./style.css", gulp.series("style"));
});
```

Comment: i got this code from wesbos.com where i was refreshing my css/flexbox knowledge.

Comment: so the terminal stopped at starting 'watch'...